Most efficient way to process packages of 8 bytes (load, process, store) with AVX2?
I have a very large amount of data in chuncks of 8 bytes. What is the most efficient way to process those using AVX2 ?
For each chunk, I would like to load the 8 bytes from memory in a 8x32 bit integer AVX register, do the processing with 8x32 bit integer AVX instructions and write the result in an output buffer, again in 8 elements of 8 bits (i.e. 8 consequtive bytes). The processing is simple so the whole procedure should be RAM bandwidth bound.
I tried:
    // Load 8 bytes into a 128-bit XMM register using _mm_loadl_epi64
    __m128 temp = _mm_loadl_pi(_mm_setzero_ps(),(const __m64*)source);
    // Zero-extend to 256-bits in a YMM register
    __m256i x = _mm256_cvtepu8_epi32(_mm_castps_si128(temp));

    ... process x

  tmp = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(xi,-1,-1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1, 12,8,4,0,
                            -1,-1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1, -1,-1,-1,-1, 12,8,4,0);
  tmp_low = tmp.get_low();
  tmp_high = tmp.get_high();
  packed = blend4i<0,4,-1,-1>( tmp_low, tmp_high );       
  _mm_storel_pi( (__m64*)p, _mm_castsi128_ps(packed));
    

But this seems to give only 25 GB/s which is only a fraction of the expected RAM throughput (100 GB/s for my machine).
Could it be that the 8 byte chunks somehow only utilize half of each RAM transaction cycle, which actuall accomodates 16 bytes ? Are smaller writes not somehwo buffered within the CPU or L1-cache before a whole 16 byte chunk is transferred to memory ?

This looks about right.  How many of these chunks do you process at the same time?  Note that narrow loads are not able to saturate the full memory bandwidth.  Can you perhaps make do with not zero extending the values?  Also try to avoid repeatedly crossing between the integer and the floating point domain.  And check the assembly to see if it actually generated the expected vpmovzxbd with a memory operand for the source.  It's hard for me to reproduce as you have failed to show either your full code or an [mcve].

Can you give some more details about what the rest of the code is (compilable, and with details about which compiler you use and with what compilation options, so we can reproduce the actual assembly code that you're running) and what CPU you're running it on. With both of them, we can do a more exact analysis of what bottlenecks you're facing. You're not writing 8-byte chunks to DRAM as such (stores are cached, unless you're writing to special memory), but there are other limits elsewhere in the system.

If you're still using a Zen2, if it's running at 3.2GHz (as some models do) and your code performs 8-byte stores as fast as possible (so 1 store per cycle) then that works out to right around 25GB/s.

Are you sure you need to convert to int32 for the "simple processing"? And assuming you need this, you can probably be slightly more efficient, if you are able to join four 8x32bit packets to one 32x8bit packet before storing.
